# Prevent JS from showing on specific pages

Tags: 6, javascript

I've got a Javascript that I'd been able to post on every page using Drupal_add_js, and everything was fine till my client's needs changed.

Now I need to show that same JS script on every site page except one node type, and one specific URL and I dont know how to do this.
I'd prefer to do it the Drupal way rather than use JS Injector if I can.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks
Steph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your logic, something along the lines of...

```
$mgo=menu_get_object();
if ((isset($mgo) && $mgo->type=='TYPE') || $_GET['q']=='PATH') {
  ;
} else {
  drupal_add_js(...);
}
```

...where you are doing your drupal_add_js(...) should do it.  I *think* this does it cleaner, but it's late in the logic day here:

```
$mgo=menu_get_object();
if ((isset($mgo) && $mgo->type!='TYPE') && $_GET['q']!='PATH') {
  drupal_add_js(...);
}
```

ADDITION:

```
$mgo=menu_get_object();
if (isset($mgo) && $mgo->type=='products') || strpos($_GET['q'], 'user/preference_center/ratings_reviews/')===0) {
  ; // do nothing
} else {
  drupal_add_js(....);
}
```

will add js only if you are not looking at a product node or not in a path that starts with user/preference_center/ratings_reviews/ BUT please note that if what is after user/preference_center/ratings_reviews is a node, this won't work because that path is actually node/#, so you will have to then do...

```
$mgo=menu_get_object();
if (isset($mgo) && $mgo->type=='products') || strpos(drupal_get_path_alias(), 'user/preference_center/ratings_reviews/')===0) {
  ; // do nothing
} else {
  drupal_add_js(....);
}
```

..instead.

Comment: I think `if ((!isset($mgo) || (isset($mgo) && $mgo->type!='TYPE')) && $_GET['q']!='PATH') {` would work in more cases

Comment: Hi Guys, I'm sorry but these replies don't work.
I've used           <?php
$mgo=menu_get_object();
if ((isset($mgo) && $mgo->type!='products') || $_GET['q']!='user/preference_center/ratings_reviews/*'):?>
test
<?php endif; ?>
and I'm not getting the results I'm hoping for. I need to get "test" off of node type "products" and URLs that contain the path section "user/preference_center/ratings_reviews/"

Comment: that's not what exactly what you asked for in the original section...brb with an addition to the answer

Comment: The $mgo var didn't work for me, but I did end up using this as my guide for hiding JS from my specific pages

Answer (score 0):

I just started working with JS & Drupal, but this might work: If you put it in the the template.php under the the YOURTHEME_preprocess_node() you can do something like:

```
<?php
$node = menu_get_object();
  if (isset($node)) 
  {
       if ($node->type = 'THENODETHATDOESNTNEEDIT') 
       {
       //Do some stuff
       }
       else 
       {
       //ADD YOUR JAVASCRIPT HERE
       }
  }
?>
```

This should drop Javascript only into the nodes you want...